# Is the extended arithmetic derivative continuous?

Tags: number-theory, continuity, arithmetic-derivative

Is the extended [arithmetic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative) continuous?  Where we extend the normal arithmetic derivative with the quotient rule, making $x':\mathbb Q\mapsto\mathbb Q$.

$$p'=1,~p\text{ is prime}\\(ab)'=a'b+ab'\\(-a)'=-a'\\\left(\frac ab\right)'=\frac{a'b-ab'}{b^2}$$

From here we can derive that $0=0'=1'$.

I can then see, for example, that the following sequence tends to $0$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)'=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-n}{2^n}=0$$

> Though I fail to manage the general case of whether the arithmetic derivative is continuous in a neighborhood of zero.
>
> Is it continuous anywhere else?

It is said to be continuous at $x$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$ if

$$x'=\lim_{a\to x,~a\in\mathbb Q}a'$$

Comment: What does continuity mean in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @orlp Oh, right, this is $\mathbb Q\mapsto\mathbb Q$, and it is continuous if $x'=\lim_{a\to x,a\in\mathbb Q}a'$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: No, it is not continuous at 0 or anywhere else. I read this by following your Wikipedia link.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ah, I missed that part under "inequalities and bounds".  I'm still interested in the proof, which the Wikipedia does not give.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I see that you have created ([tag:arithmetic-derivative]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/arithmetic-derivative/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak I've never made a tag before, so never knew of such things.

Comment: Creating a tag for a single posting is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I do not intend this to be the only question with the tag.  Just yesterday there was a question on the HNQ concerning arithmetic derivatives.

Comment: Then why didn't you tag _that_ question accordingly?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I was asleep soon after posting this question, but it is now tagged accordingly.

Comment: Good. You might want to run a search on "arithmetic derivative" and tag some more questions, so that the new tag of yours would be immediately useful for those who will follow it.

Comment: Since it seems that the comments here somewhat digressed from the actual question to best practices for tag creation, I will suggests that if further discussion of newly created tag is needed, we can continue in the [tagging chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/6/1).

Comment: As for the proof, it is supposedly there in the arXiv paper referenced on the same Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [$p$-adic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) viewpoint gives some nice intuition into the global discontinuity.

First fix a prime $p$ and define the restricted arithmetical derivative as:
$$
(p^n)'^{_p} = n p^{n-1}\\
a'^{_p} = 0
$$
Where $a \in \mathbb{Z}, (a,p) = 1$, and then extending to all of $\mathbb{Q}$ using the Leibniz rule for products and quotients.

The normal arithmetic derivative is then given for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ by:
$$
x' = \sum_{p \in \mathbb{P}} x'^{_p}
$$
Now consider $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$, any $x$ can be written as $x=p^n a$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}, a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the $p$-adic integers. By the product rule, $x'^{_p} = (p^n a)'^{_p} = (p^n)'^{_p} a \ + p^n a'^{_p} = n p^{n-1}a = \frac{nx}{p}$.

For any sequence $(x_i)$ converging to $x$, we must have that, for all $i>N$ for some sufficiently large $N$, that $|x_i|_p = |x|_p$, and therefore that $x_i = p^n b$ for the same $n$ as $x$. Then we can show continuity of this derivative.

$\forall \varepsilon > 0$ if we have $|x_i - x|_p < \delta$ then $|(x_i)'^{_p}-x'^{_p}|_p=\left|\frac{nx_i}{p}-\frac{nx}{p}\right|_p=p \ |n|_p |x_i-x|_p$ $< p \ |n|_p \delta = \varepsilon$, for $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{p \ |n|_p}$.

Therefore the restricted arithmetic derivative is continuous over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all $p$, and as $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}_p$, it is continuous under the $p$-adic metric over the rationals.

The trouble comes when we attempt to unrestrict the derivative. Taking the normal arithmetic derivative, we have a sum of restricted derivatives who are each continuous over a different $\mathbb{Q}_p$. A sequence $(x_i)$ that gets closer in one metric, may not get closer with respect to another, thus leading to sequences that converge over the real metric, but will not converge over every $p$-adic metric, thus implying there will always exist infinitely many sequences that are not continuous under the mapping given by the arithmetic derivative, no matter how small of a neighborhood you consider.

Answer (score 5):

Let $n$ be a large integer. Let $p=p(n)$ be a prime in the neighborhood of $\sqrt n2^n$. E.g., by Bertrand, we know there's a prime $p$ between $\sqrt n2^n$ and $2\sqrt n2^n$. Note that $(2^n)/p\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. $$\left({2^n\over p}\right)'={pn2^{n-1}-2^n\over p^2}={n\over2}{2^n\over p}-{2^n\over p^2}\to\infty$$ as $n\to\infty$, a pretty serious violation of continuity at zero.

Comment: Still good answer, though Paul LeVan's answer is far more general (and quite nice) so I accepted his instead.